# QLPreviewPanel in tableview with issue: "has no controller"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsviewcontroller, quicklook, qlpreviewcontroller

I would like to display the urls from a table view in a QLPreviewPanel but i got this error:

> [QL] QLError(): -[QLPreviewPanel reloadData] called while the panel
>   has no controller - Fix this or this will raise soon.

My table controller already conform to this two protocols : QLPreviewPanelDataSource, QLPreviewPanelDelegate.

How can i set the controller of `[QLPreviewPanel sharedPreviewPanel]` as my table controller?

```
- (void)didPressSpacebarForTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView {
    NSLog(@"Spacebar clicked");
    if ([QLPreviewPanel sharedPreviewPanelExists] && [[QLPreviewPanel sharedPreviewPanel] isVisible]) {
        [[QLPreviewPanel sharedPreviewPanel] orderOut:nil];
    } else {
        [[QLPreviewPanel sharedPreviewPanel] reloadData];
        [[QLPreviewPanel sharedPreviewPanel] makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
    }
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfPreviewItemsInPreviewPanel:(QLPreviewPanel *)panel {
    return [[(PasteboardItem *)[[_arrayController arrangedObjects] objectAtIndex:[_tableView selectedRow]] filenames] count];
}


- (id<QLPreviewItem>)previewPanel:(QLPreviewPanel *)panel previewItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    NSString *path = [(PasteboardItem *)[[_arrayController arrangedObjects] objectAtIndex:[_tableView selectedRow]] filenames][index];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    return url;
}

- (BOOL)acceptsPreviewPanelControl:(QLPreviewPanel *)panel {
    return YES;
}

-(void)beginPreviewPanelControl:(QLPreviewPanel *)panel {
    panel.dataSource = self;
    panel.delegate = self;
}

- (void)endPreviewPanelControl:(QLPreviewPanel *)panel {
    panel.dataSource = nil;
    panel.delegate = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution here: [QuickLook consumer as a delegate from an NSViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836782/quicklook-consumer-as-a-delegate-from-an-nsviewcontroller?rq=1). In my case i need these 3 lines of code in the panel controller (NSWindowController) where i have the instance of my table view controller.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib { 
    NSResponder * aNextResponder = [self nextResponder];
    [self setNextResponder:_tableController];
    [_tableController setNextResponder:aNextResponder];
}
```